# Is "my IDE crashed" question on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Apple released Xcode6-beta3 and there are lots question about it crashed. Are these kind of questions on-topic? We can't really fix Xcode bug for them. We may (but not always) able to suggest workaround.

Examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643639/swift-xcode-6-playground-keeps-crashing-while-typing-my-code

[Can't get dynamicType of a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643616/cant-get-dynamictype-of-a-closure)

[Using @lazy properties in functions causes build errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052352/using-lazy-properties-in-functions-causes-build-errors)

Most the time the only thing we can do it saying "It looks like a bug. You need to file a bug report".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On-topic? Sure - assuming the IDE qualifies as a "[software tool commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" that is, and most do.

Of course, the question still needs to be clear and detailed enough to be *answerable* - but that's a separate issue. If it is possible for others to identify and reproduce the problem, then it's possible for them to answer and potentially (as you noted) suggest a work-around that'll accomplish the same ends *without* crashing.

Questions that fail to actually outline a specific enough task for others to suggest work-arounds are probably better suited, as George notes, for bug reports.