# Do questions about setting up IDE's belong on SO?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If someone has a problem with setting up their IDE, and decides to ask, does that question belong on SO?

Comment: Related: [Is "My IDE crashed" question on-topic here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263052/is-my-ide-crashed-question-on-topic-here)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given that IDEs qualify as "software tools commonly used by programmers", and questions about those are generally on-topic here as per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I don't see why not, given that there isn't anything else about the question that would make it bad.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but that doesn't mean you won't find 5 people to look at such a question and close it down as off-topic within a few minutes (on the basis that the subject of the question is not on-topic, assuming it's on-topic in terms of suitability for a Q&A)...

Comment: @Bruno Yeah, not much you can do about that at times besides reopen and hope other people will agree

Comment: There's a difference, though, between a question like "How do I download and install this particular IDE?" and "How do I change the way my code is formatted". The first is general software use (no different than "How do I download and install WinZip/7zip/Open Office/some random game or software?"), while the second is about *use* of a programming tool. IMO the first is off-topic, while the second is appropriate.