# Review Audit Failed - When are IDE questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

A while ago I failed this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31036365). The question appears to me to be asking how to enable an option within a specific IDE, which to my mind, would not be considered a programming issue but one of knowledge of the IDE in question. However, flagging this question as **About general computing hardware and software** caused me to fail the audit.

Is there any guidance as to when questions regarding the use of an IDE are on topic? and at what point would this sort of question become off topic?

Comment: Visual Studio is a programming tool. It's not used for anything but programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers; and is**
> - **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Enabling an option in Visual Studio definitely qualifies as both: a software tool commonly used by programmers and is unique to software development.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the "and is"?

Comment: @Braiam: Is enabling a IDE feature not practical? Or not answerable? Or not unique to software development?

Comment: Well, then why you stopped short of stating so? If enabling a IDE feature is all of that, you should mark all of those that apply.

Comment: BTW, my comment is [in the line of this other comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263131/do-questions-about-setting-up-ides-belong-on-so#comment56288_263134)