# Would a question about details of user interaction with an IDE be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am using NetBeans and there's a (really minor) issue about its user interface that's been bothering me, but for which various google queries have not turned up any useful solutions (as a matter of fact, not even any use*less* ones - just nothing). So I've been wondering if it would be appropriate to ask it here.

Now, I already found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263052/), the answer to which seems to be generally in favor, but refers to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which mentions that the question should (among other things) be

> ... a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**

(emphasis mine). The matter about which I would want to inquire is, however, not unique to software development in the strictest sense - it could apply to any kind of text editor used for any kind of purpose.

So - am I reading the rules too strictly? Or would such a question really be better placed somewhere else? If the latter, what would you recommend?

Comment: I think it should be interpreted as for example "you can ask questions about your browser's developer tools, but you cannot ask questions on general usage of your browser".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - ...
> - software tools commonly used by programmers ...
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Yes, IDE questions are on-topic, as they relate to "tools commonly used by programmers". There are in fact a bunch of such questions on SO and nobody ever had a problem with them so far.

Having said that, your question may or may not be appropriate for SO in general. If it's some minutiae about a UI issue which doesn't specifically have anything to do with IDEs but could equally apply to any piece of software, it *may* be better at http://superuser.com. Additionally, if it's more of a bug report than a question, the vendor's bug tracker may be a better place to post it. The issue should pretty directly be related to *software development* in order to be on-topic on SO.