# Question about accomplishing something in IDE put on hold as off-topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, close-reasons

I just answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543182/open-a-qt-creator-buffer-in-emacs) that got put on hold as being off-topic, with the standard reason:

> "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

According to this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266778/3854787), questions about IDEs are on-topic on SO.

Although the asker says he uses a plugin to accomplish his goal in Firefox, he's not exactly asking for a recommendation: Any way to accomplish it is fine. The excerpt about the plugin is merely an example of what he was trying to achieve. And it turns out Qt Creator does have a way that needs no additional software, as my answer states.

Why was the question put on hold as off-topic?

Comment: It reads as *find me a tool*. I gave it an edit and a re-open vote. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: This isn't clear-cut enough to me to get me off of the fence.  I'll keep my close vote in my pocket until I can formulate some reason why it should be reopened.  I don't disagree that it feels like it *should* be reopened, but something about it doesn't make me feel like it *must* be reopened.

Comment: @Makoto I was tempted to edit out the noise but when I tried I had the feeling nothing was left.

Comment: This is borderline too broad, but we can give it a shot.

Comment: The biography and digression into web browser plugins weren't really helping the cause.

Comment: _"According to this answer, questions about IDEs are on-topic on SO."_ I see this reasoning quite a lot, and it just doesn't hold up. Just because questions about IDEs aren't off-topic because they're about IDEs, doesn't mean that _every_ question about an IDE is on-topic. Other factors need to be taken into consideration.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was merely providing counterarguments for the probable reasons the question may have been voted to close. I wasn't trying to imply **every** question about an IDE is on-topic: This is not true even for questions about programming languages.

Comment: @CássioRenan: Good! Some (other) people mean it that way when they say it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The original question was a plugin (tool) recommendation question and was therefore correctly closed, since such questions are explicitly off-topic on SO. It doesn't matter that the question is about a tool used by programmers. You have to view the edit history to see the original:

> I'm a 30+ year veteran of emacs, now working on a Qt based product suite. I see the advantages of using the blessed IDE, Qt Creator, so I want to include it in my workflow for a bit more than just browsing/searching code. However...
>
> As with Eclipse, just giving me some key bindings via a plug-in is more an exercise in frustration than a help. There are things I want to do in emacs that simple key bindings don't help (macros come to mind).
>
> I use a plugin with Firefox, called "It's All Text!", which allows me to spawn an emacs instance with the text of the current form. When I've made edits, I save and exit, and the results are transferred back to Firefox.
>
> I'd like something very like that for Qt Creator. Any chance it exists?

This is a tool recommendation question, plain and simple.

---

Examples of on-topic questions:

- How to use plugin x in IDE y? Description about the OP's attempts so far follows.
- Why doesn't plugin x work in IDE y? Descriptions about what the OP has tried follows.

Examples of off-topic questions:

- Is there a plugin you can recommend for...
- Which plugin/IDE is best...
- Where can I find plugin x?

After several revisions due to the "meta effect" of you posting here and thereby giving the post extra attention, the question was made on-topic (and had irrelevant fluff removed) and is now open again.

Comment: What kind of annoys me is that none of the people who saw the question *before* the meta effect kicked in, including the five close voters, apparently felt any inclination to make even a minimal edit to rephrase the question in the correct and approved manner. It seems that many people on SO would rather close questions for using the wrong shibboleth (such as asking "Is there a *tool* to do X in Y?" instead of "Is there a *way* to do X in Y?") than edit them and just fix the phrasing.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It is perfectly fine, and even preferred, not to try to crystal ball out what the OP is trying to ask, but to put the question _on hold_ and give them time to fix it themselves. By closing off-topic questions, we educate people how to use the site. By fixing them, we teach people it's fine to ask bad questions and they should keep doing so. I guess it would be nice if someone left a comment for the OP. But in this case the OP in this case is a veteran user with _lots_ of rep and should really be knowing better.

Comment: I'd agree with that if a) the required change wasn't both obvious and purely cosmetic in many cases like this one, b) we actually provided useful guidance to the asker about what they said wrong and how to rephrase their question, instead of telling them to read this [wall of text](/q/254393) and puzzle it out, and c) if, after being edited to make it on-topic, an average question actually had a reasonable chance of getting reopened via review.

Comment: (FWIW, [over 90% of reopen reviews get declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306399), although that statistic is obviously skewed by the large number of useless edits on closed questions. Still, IME, even for questions that *have* been fixed and are now perfectly on-topic, the success rate seems to be well under 50%.)

Answer (score 18):

People who act like they're trying to write prose, poems or books instead of clear, concise posts tend to get their posts downvoted for being unclear or close-voted for the same reason.

What they were really trying to ask, *"How can I host an Emacs editor window in Qt Creator?"*, doesn't need three paragraphs including a biography and an explanation of what extensions are.

[Josh's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49543182/revisions) was much needed and clarified the post enough to warrant reopening. When people post unclear posts, we don't go blame the people who down- or closevote it. The post should've been clear from the beginning. Do remember closure isn't an end station, it's a signal that a post *in its current form* isn't good enough for the site.

Comment: This is however not why the question was closed. It was closed since it was originally a tool recommendation question.