# Failed Close Vote Audit - Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: discussion, scope, disputed-review-audits

So I just failed a [close vote review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16942441), and I am quite certain that the audit case is wrong, however I know that I am far from perfect.

This is the second audit that I failed, and after I failed the first one I spent some time re-reviewing that first post. I came to the conclusion that I should have skipped it, and every subsequent vote was only cast if I was absolutely 100% certain - and that has me worried that I have perhaps been wrong more often than is acceptable.

From my point of view, the question was referencing a bug in a software suite, which is off topic? I have re-read it a few times and I keep coming to the conclusion that my close vote is correct. And I specifically don't mean "unsure"/"skip", it genuinely looks off-topic to me.

That means that one of two things occurred:

1. [The audit was incorrect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303802/6049581), or
2. I am incorrect.

I would love to think that it's the audit that was incorrect, but it would be naive of me to simply assume such and move on without some form of confirmation and/or correction.

**If the audit was incorrect**: I would sincerely just appreciate confirmation that I haven't jumped the gun.

**If I am incorrect**: I would like some assistance in understanding where I went wrong with this audit, so that I can ensure I adjust my frame of reference regarding close votes so that in future I don't vote to close a legitimate question.

I am going through the close vote queue with the specific intentions to help, and I fully understand that I am only causing damage if I consistently vote incorrectly, and would like to avoid this.

Comment: Why do you think a bug in a software suite is off-topic? Questions about [software tools commonly used by programmers;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are on topic.

Comment: [Related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263052/is-my-ide-crashed-question-on-topic-here/263055#263055) about bugs in software tools used for programming.

Comment: @RobertLongson I did read through that after the audit, but I had understood that as "_I am using SoftwareX and the code produced by using OptionY is causing ResultA instead of ResultB_".  In my mind, the question belonged in a bug report and I did not consider that the answers were based on working around the bug, which actually proves the validity of the question  (thanks for the link @Keiwan). Thank you both for your insight :) It's exactly what I was looking for,

Comment: Yes, bug reports about software tools commonly used by programmers *are* on-topic, as long as they are phrased as an answerable question (which is usually how can I work around this, but it can also work to just ask "is this a bug?"). Thanks for asking about this when you were uncertain. The point here is to learn, and now you know! :-) You aren't review-banned, so no harm done.